# simple update query taking very long to execute in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance

I was checking the slow-query-log of MySQL, and found out an entry as below:

```
# Time: 131108  4:16:34

# Query_time: 14.726425  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1383884194;
UPDATE `Artist` SET ImageFilename = NULL, Title = 'Elton John', PopularityRating = 657, UniqueID = NULL, Description = NULL, IsFeatured = 0, FeaturedText = '', MetaDescription = '', MetaTitle = NULL, _Temporary_LastUpdOn = '2013-11-08 04:15:58 ', _Temporary_Flag = 0, _Deleted = 0, _DeletedOn = NULL, Priority = 0 WHERE ID = 3449748;
```

As you can see, it took a staggering 14.72sec to perform this query, when it is a simple update with just a `WHERE` by primary key.  I've tried re-executing the query, but now it executing in 0.095sec which is much more reasonable.

Any ideas how I can debug why at that specific time it took so long?

**Edit 1: query_cache% variables**

```
mysql> SHOW variables where variable_name like 'query_cache%';
+------------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name                | Value     |
+------------------------------+-----------+
| query_cache_limit            | 1048576   |
| query_cache_min_res_unit     | 4096      |
| query_cache_size             | 210763776 |
| query_cache_type             | ON        |
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate | OFF       |
+------------------------------+-----------+
```

**Edit 2: Artist table info**

```
CREATE TABLE `artist` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `ImageFilename` mediumtext,
  `Title` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PopularityRating` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `UniqueID` mediumtext,
  `Description` mediumtext,
  `IsFeatured` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `FeaturedText` mediumtext,
  `_Temporary_LastUpdOn` datetime DEFAULT '0001-01-01 00:00:00',
  `_Temporary_Flag` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `_Deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `_DeletedOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Priority` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `MetaDescription` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MetaTitle` mediumtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `_Temporary_Flag` (`_Temporary_Flag`),
  KEY `_Deleted` (`_Deleted`),
  KEY `Priority` (`Priority`),
  KEY `PopularityRating` (`PopularityRating`),
  KEY `Title` (`Title`(255)),
  KEY `IsFeatured` (`IsFeatured`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Maybe the table was locked that time.

Comment: Do you have cache enabled? Maybe farfetched but if a query alters the cached results then a performance dip can occur.

Comment: @KayNelson How can I know if I have cache-enabled?

Comment: @KarlCassar execute this SHOW variables where variable_name like 'query_cache%';

Comment: Can you post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE Artist`, please?

Comment: @KayNelson Just updated the post with the output.

Comment: @JoshuaMartell added output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE ARTIST` to post.

Comment: Assumption is, it's either date formatting, caching, low physical memory or silly-level of indexing. You can verify these by trying to update several items several times -keep monitoring ram and cpu usage, ram mainly- to see if everything and always slow, whatever you do or not. Also, try to update columns one by one as you may find the bottleneck (crazy-indexing of one or more columns, date formatting/converting, etc). If nothing works it's the db sys environment (cache, ram usage policies/rules, hdd issues, etc)

Comment: Did you try any of the suggestions?

Comment: What was actually happening with your server at that time? Could you at least post your average %iowait and CPU idle time? Are there chances that you hit a moment when your drives were 100% utilized?

Answer (score 1):

Given the output you have provided, my suggestion here would be to minimize your cache size. Its is ofcourse only my best assumption that this caused the update time to span over 15 seconds because the query itself is optimal using `WHERE` on `PRIMARY KEY`.

Since you havent been able to reproduced the problem its hard to determine.

I was reading the cache documentation again to get some info.

> When tables are modified, any relevant entries in the query cache are flushed. 
>   This could be a reason for the update you did that it had to flush cached data.

Another part of the docmentation

> Be cautious about sizing the query cache excessively large, which
>   increases the overhead required to maintain the cache, possibly beyond
>   the benefit of enabling it. Sizes in tens of megabytes are usually
>   beneficial. Sizes in the hundreds of megabytes might not be.

Either way, since you have the query cache enabled, i think thats a good starting point.

To set a new query cache while in production

```
SET GLOBAL query_cache_size = 1000000;
```

Mysql will automatically set the size to be aligned to the nearest 1024 byte block.

Read this documentation well, its very helpful to understand. Query cache can at the same time be your best and your worst setting.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem of your table. You created several indexes for the table, which includes fields you will update in the sql. Then mysql has to reconstruct the index everytime.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not tuned MySQL server variables, It is important to tune server variables to increase performance. It is recommended to have a look at the key_buffer_size and table_cache variables.

The key_buffer_size variable controls the amount of memory available for the MySQL index buffer. The higher this value, the more memory available for indexes and better the performance.

The table_cache variable controls the amount of memory available for the table cache, and thus the total number of tables MySQL can hold open at any given time. For busy servers with many databases and tables, this value should be increased so that MySQL can serve all requests reliably.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone missed the comment above:

> Maybe the table was locked that time.

Since you could not reproduce the problem, this was likely the case.